# Randomizing job scheduling with cron and sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sidekiq-cron

I am building a small crawler/scraper for my dad! I am trying to randomize scrape times every week (meaning I want the scrape method to fire off every week at a different day and time of day).

I tried the rewrite the YAML file every time the method fires off that does not seem to work... Then I tried the "set" method:

```
def set_random_schedule(author_name)
  cron_expression = random_cron_expression
  self.class.set(cron: cron_expression).perform_async(author_name)
end

def random_cron_expression
  "#{rand(1..3)} * * * *}"
end
```

In the logs it said it was running almost every second, I honestly don't know why... Or if I read it wrong I am really new to sidekiq and cron so I am not sure where did I go wrong. Bare with me here please.

Any help to beginner? Feel free to explain or reference whatever comes to mind I am always keen to learn.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I wouldn't be using cron at all. Just have some code at the end of your `perform` that schedules another sidekiq task for the future at your randomized time. Like:

```rb
def perform(your, args)

  ## do your stuff

  ThisModule.perform_at(random_time, your, args)
end

def random_time
  next_week = 1.week.from_now
  start_of_nw = next_week.beginning_of_week
  seconds_in_nw = ( start_of_nw + 1.week ) - start_of_nw

  start_of_nw + rand(seconds_in_nw)
end
```

Note that the `random_time` is a little more complex than you might expect in order to account for daylight savings switches.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! 

I tried this:

I called this in the perform method

ScraperWorker.perform_at(random_time)

and here is the random_time method

def random_time
    times = [60, 120, 180]
    rand(times.sample)
  end


but no luck... 

Also when I was using cron it started only enqueueing jobs but not executing them... ‍♂️ I am really not sure what am I ding wrong. Is there anything I could provide in order to get you more complete picture of where am I going wrong without overwhelming you?

Comment: Well obviously `perform_at(180)` isn't going to work, as my code demonstrates - it expects a time object. Your question said _"every week at a different day and time of day"_, hence my code.

Comment: Apologies. Thank you for your time! I will try your approach properly. I tried to rewrite the yaml file and that works but now I need to figure out a more efficient way for deployment purposes.  One more time thank you!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your job, you can try to add this code to reschedule its cron timer:

```
scrape_job = Sidekiq::Cron::Job.all.find{ |job| job.klass == "YourClassNameJob"}
scrape_job.cron = "#{rand(1..3)} * * * *}"
scrape_job.save
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

def randomize_times_of_scraping
    puts "Randomized started"
    scrape_job = Sidekiq::Cron::Job.all.find { |job| job.klass == "ScraperWorker" }
    scrape_job.cron = "#{rand(1..3)} * * * *}"
    scrape_job.save
  end

This is the method I used and it did not seem to work. It doesn't randomise the time of scraping. It still scrapes every 5 minutes. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also I called randomize_times_of_scraping in the perform method.

Comment: Can you try to run this in your rails console to see if your job's cron time is changing at /sidekiq/cron, or is it throwing any errors?

Comment: I gave it go again and every time it fired of randomise_time method I reloaded the console and checked and it was still every 5 minutes... I tried this as well:

```
def randomize_times_of_scraping
    puts "Randomized started"
    self.class.update(cron: "#{rand(1..3)} * * * *}")
  end
```

This enques the job but doesn't fir it off...